# Type '...' is not assignable to type '...' when using a context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am using `createContext` in Next.js to create a dark mode button; here's the `ThemeContext.tsx`, it's originally a normal `jsx` file; I am trying to convert it to TypeScript.

```js
"use client";

import { useState, createContext } from "react";

type ThemeContextType = "light" | "dark";

interface ChildrenProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>("light");

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: ChildrenProps) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<string>("dark");

  const toggle = (): void => {
    setMode((prev) => (prev === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"));
  };
  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ toggle, mode }}>
      <div className={`theme ${mode}`}>{children}</div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

I got the error from the `value` in `ThemeContext.Provider value={{toggle, mode}}>`

```
Type '{ toggle: () => void; mode: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ThemeContextType'.ts(2322)

index.d.ts(329, 9): The expected type comes from property 'value' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ProviderProps<ThemeContextType>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `ThemeContextType`, because, as of now, it makes it so the `value` of the provider can only accept a string equal to "light" or "dark". This should work:

```
"use client";

import { useState, createContext } from "react";

type ModeType = "light" | "dark";
type ThemeContextType = {
  mode: ModeType;
  toggle: () => void;
};

interface ChildrenProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const ThemeContext = createContext<ThemeContextType>({ mode: "light", toggle: () => {} });

export const ThemeProvider = ({ children }: ChildrenProps) => {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState<ModeType>("dark");

  const toggle = (): void => {
    setMode((prev) => (prev === "dark" ? "light" : "dark"));
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ toggle, mode }}>
      <div className={`theme ${mode}`}>{children}</div>
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: So if I set the type of `ThemeContext` to be `"light" | "dark"`, the property of it `ThemeContext.Provider` will also inherit the type of `ThemeContext` ?

Comment: Yes, the type you give to `createContext` will be the type of `value` of `ThemeContext.Provider`.